# Posting Large File to Remote App

Tags: 2013, office-365, app

I am trying to implement functionality by which you can post a large file (85MB+) to an autohosted app.

I have tested locally and the functionality works.  As soon as I deploy to O365, large files start returning a 502 error.

I have modified the httpRuntime element in the web.config, so that is not the issue.

Has anyone seen this before? Workaround?

**EDIT:** 35MB causes a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer.  Turns out it was being blocked by request filtering.  Add the below to web.config to resolve issue.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```